# golang os.Close() function works, but os.Remove() function does not

Tags: go

I am trying to create a file, open it, do some processing on it & close it. Finally, I want to delete the file.
All these operations are executed successfully, except the deletion.

My code is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
    metaFileName := "./metadata.txt"
    _, err2 := os.Create(metaFileName)
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err2)
    }
    
    openMetaFile, err := os.Open(metaFileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    err = openMetaFile.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    err = os.Remove(metaFileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    fmt.Println("Success")
}
```

The output is:

```
Hello
2020/08/24 00:00:00 remove ./metadata.txt: The process cannot access the file be
cause it is being used by another process.
```

I am clueless about this

Comment: Just to be sure: you dont have that file opened in some other editor or so?

Comment: No, the file was not opened in any editor. To my surprise, there is no issue when I run the same code on Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related to the first opened file.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

const metaFileName = "./metadata.txt"

func main() {
    var (
        err                   error
        tmpFile, openMetaFile *os.File
    )

    fmt.Println("Hello")
    if tmpFile, err = os.Create(metaFileName); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err = tmpFile.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if openMetaFile, err = os.Open(metaFileName); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err = openMetaFile.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err = os.Remove(metaFileName); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Success")
}
```

As you can see, i've used the var `a` in order to close the first file that you have opened. The result is following one:

```
Hello
Success
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! To my surprise, the issue was there only in Windows; earlier code works absolutely fine in Ubuntu, I don't know why?

Comment: It's because Unix and Windows have a different way to manage open files.

Comment: Specifically, POSIX `unlink` waits until the file is no longer in use before it's removed. https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Deleting-Files.html